# Search for field in object

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, resharper-6.0

Is there any way (or Plug-In) for Visual Studio 2010 to search for field in a .net object?
For example: say I debug and watch in Quickwatch an object. I look for a specific field that I know the value, but not where the field is (for example: A->base3->base2->base1->someField). I want to search for the value and find witch field got that value.

Answer (score 0):

The tool I recommended before as an answer got removed and link became a spam site, so I wanted to make an effort to find another tool for this.

This seems to be a feature for `OzCode` - a well established debugger tool for `Visual Studio`

https://github.com/oz-code/OzCodeDemo/tree/master/OzCodeDemo/02.Search

https://oz-code.com/

**Update**

Turns out `BugAid` (the tool I recommended previously) was just renamed into `OzCode`. So this is the same tool (but way better now than it was in 2012)